# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs, state

I have a filter function which is filtering data with state data, dataCopy and searchValue. Issue is if i don't include the data state than react gives warning and if i do include it it cause infinite loop cause the data array is changing within the useEffect. How can i make so that i don't get that warning.

**Filter function**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Header from '../Components/Header/Header'
import Home from '../Components/Home/Home'
import "./Layout.css"
import Spinner from '../Components/Spinner/Spinner'

function Layout() {

    // state for data, copy of data and spinner
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [dataCopy, setDataCopy] = useState([])

    // state for search input in Header.js (define in parent )
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("")

    // changing search value
    const changeSearchValue = (value) => {
        setSearchValue(value)
    }


    // useEffect for search functionality
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleSearch = () => {
            if (searchValue !== "") {
                
                const searchFilter = data.filter(item =>
                    !isNaN(searchValue) ? item.expected_annually_bill_amount.toString().includes(searchValue) :
                        item.dmo_content.Ausgrid.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
                setData(searchFilter)
            } else {
                setData(dataCopy)
            }

        }
        handleSearch()
    }, [searchValue, dataCopy])





    // useEffect for getting data from api
    useEffect(() => {
        // making post request to get the token
        axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}`, { data: "" },
            {
                headers:
                {
                    'Api-key': `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
                },
            })
            // after getting to token returning it for callback
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data.data.token
            })
            // using the token to call another api for the needed data
            .then((tokenIs) => {
                axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DATA_URL}`,
                    { "session_id": `${process.env.REACT_APP_SESSION_ID}` },
                    {
                        headers:
                        {
                            'Api-key': `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
                            'Auth-token': tokenIs,
                        },
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        setData(response.data.data.electricity)
                        setDataCopy(response.data.data.electricity)
                        setSpinner(false)
                    })
            })
            // catiching any error if happens
            .catch((err) => {
                setSpinner(false)
                alert(err)
            })

    }, [])


    return (<>
       
            <div className='layout'>
                <Header
                    changeSearchValue={changeSearchValue}
                    searchValue={searchValue}
                />
                <Home data={data} />
            </div>
        
    
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can eliminate `data` dependency by:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const handleSearch = () => {
            if (searchValue !== "") {
                setData(data => data.filter(item =>
                    !isNaN(searchValue) ? item.expected_annually_bill_amount.toString().includes(searchValue) :
                        item.dmo_content.Ausgrid.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())))
            } else {
                setData(dataCopy)
            }

        }
        handleSearch()
    }, [searchValue, dataCopy])
```

Comment: This is correct answer, dont depend on state you are changing, instead use callback function in setState function

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following comment above the dependency array for suppressing the warning

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```